# How is a program with many functions stored in a text segment?

Tags: c, operating-system, ram

Let us say I have a simple c program written to compute the result of a number raised to a power of 2. This is handled by a function called `pow(a,n)`. The main function just takes in a user input, calls this function with the number and prints the returned result. After I compile and run this program, I think the entire function would be in the text segment in physical memory. Is this correct? When does the stack come into the picture here?

Comment: So the code I write for main and pow will be compiled and will reside in the code/text segment in the physical memory(let's say). When main is called first, it executes until the code for call to pow(a,n). At this point, the local variables of main and the return address will be pushed onto the stack and the next instruction (from pow(a,n) will be fetched from the text segment of the program and executed. Is this correct? In other words, is the entire code of a binary in the text segment when loaded into the physical memory?

Answer (score 0):

`When does the stack come into the picture here?`

Before calling this library function `pow(a,n)`, you declare a variable inside your main function isn't, those variable is allocated on the stack.

`text segment in physical memory. Is this correct?`

This is irrelevant because of the technique called Virtual Memory, which makes your program feel it has access to address on RAM even your program data/text etc., is present somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled program will be stored in the text segment from where the instruction are fetched for execution. Address of the function will be know to process( program under execution ) as it is globally declared in a separate table called symbol table .

The stack it C comes in to picture a function call is made. It needs its own place to store the local variables  (Frame pointer and passed parameters to the function and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Mostly stack will be used for two purpose.

1. For storing local variables. say  a, b in main()
2. Call stack.

   ```
   int main()
   {
      int a = 5, b = 10; //Stored in Stack    
      pow(a,b); //stack role - Call stack for returning control to main function    
   }

   void pow(int x, int y)
   {
     int v; //stack involved here too.
      .....
   }
   ```